# Is it possible to specify a supertrait such that it is generic over its type parameter?

Tags: rust

I would like to be able to say that any type that implements my trait `A` must also implement trait `B` such that the type parameter to the trait `B` can be any type that implements trait `C`. I trying to write something like the following (which isn't valid syntax apparently), where `A` is `Foo`, `B` is `Add`, and `C` is `Copy`:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

trait Foo: Sized + for<T> Add<T>
where
    T: Copy,
    <Self as Add<T>>::Output: Copy,
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply make your trait generic over `T` as well instead of using `for<T>`:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

trait Foo<T>: Sized + Add<T>
where
    T: Copy,
    <Self as Add<T>>::Output: Copy,
{
}
```